# How can i use bugzilla rest api method /bug to list the bugs

Tags: java, rest, bugzilla

Hi i have been trying to search for bugs in bugzilla through rest api methods of bugzilla. To get the bugs I developed code in java which is giving 406 error. Below is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JsonParser.ParseException,   
JSONException, ParseException {
  URL url=new URL("http:mybugzilla.com/bug");

  HttpURLConnection urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.connect();
     PrintStream printStream=new PrintStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
     //printStream.print();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new      
     InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

     String line;
     StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");

     }

     System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Api doc](https://wiki.mozilla.org/BMO/REST) you are probably missing something in your request string. 
At the very least your `URL url=new URL("http:mybugzilla.com/bug")` should be

> URL url=new URL("http://mybugzilla.com/bug")

Comment: my bugzilla url http://mybugzilla/bugzilla-2.16.4/query.cgi for searching the bug and for viewing bugs http://mybugzilla/bugzilla-2.16.4//buglist.cgi?. But when i use this url to make rest api get request i am getting 406 error.

Answer (score 0):

A sample example written in python, to get the list of public bugs from Bugzilla 5.x, using the rest API.

```
import requests

url_bz_restapi = 'http://localhost/bugzilla/rest.cgi/bug'
r = requests.get(url_bz_restapi)
```